# which class do I have to use to make photo slide show?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to make an iPhone app that shows many greeting cards, I like to show theme like this method:

[image]

Which class should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [Three20](http://three20.info/)

Comment: Thanks Control-V, I am discovering its features and it sounds like the solution that I want.